# I'd like to use VNC, with the xmonad window manager, at an arbitrary resolution

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, xmonad

In order to use an arbitrary resolution (the resolution of the client) I've found that I need to create a new display session (correct term?). If I use display 0, I can't start a VNC server at any resolution because the connected display only has a few modes, and none of them are the same as my client's resolution.

So, in order to start a VNC server that creates a new session, I use the following command to start tightvnc:

```
vncserver :12 -name "MyServer" -geometry 1440x900
```

And I have a file at `~/.vnc/xstartup` with the contents:

```
xmonad &
```

When I connect to the server remotely, it creates a new session, but as far as I can tell, it does not run xmonad. What I get is a window with a resolution of 1440x900, filled with a black and white cross-hatch pattern, and with an X for a cursor. No input seems to have any effect.

The content's of the relevant tightvnc log file are as follows

```
17/12/13 15:20:28 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
17/12/13 15:20:28 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
17/12/13 15:20:28 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
17/12/13 15:20:28 All Rights Reserved.
17/12/13 15:20:28 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
17/12/13 15:20:28 Desktop name 'MyServer' (glock:12)
17/12/13 15:20:28 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
17/12/13 15:20:28 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5912
Xlib:  extension "XINERAMA" missing on display ":12".

17/12/13 15:20:46 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 Using protocol version 3.8
17/12/13 15:20:46 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
17/12/13 15:20:46   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
17/12/13 15:20:46   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
17/12/13 15:20:46   no translation needed
17/12/13 15:20:46 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
17/12/13 15:20:46 Using tight encoding for client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 Using image quality level 6 for client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 8
17/12/13 15:20:46 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -307
17/12/13 15:20:46 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
17/12/13 15:20:46 Enabling cursor position updates for client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:46 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
17/12/13 15:20:54 Client 127.0.0.1 gone
17/12/13 15:20:54 Statistics:
17/12/13 15:20:54   key events received 18, pointer events 24
17/12/13 15:20:54   framebuffer updates 1, rectangles 23, bytes 2840
17/12/13 15:20:54     LastRect markers 1, bytes 12
17/12/13 15:20:54     cursor shape updates 1, bytes 684
17/12/13 15:20:54     cursor position updates 1, bytes 12
17/12/13 15:20:54     tight rectangles 20, bytes 2132
17/12/13 15:20:54   raw bytes equivalent 5184012, compression ratio 2431.525328
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":12"
      after 271 requests (271 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

As for any errors that might have been produced when `~/.vnc/xstartup` was run, I don't know where to find them.